# Battery saving strategy for a long running IPC service

Tags: android

I read this great blog article [Android Architecture Tutorial: Developing an App with a Background Service (using IPC)](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/37/android-architecture-tutorial-developing-an-app-with-a-background-service-using-ipc/)

The author show a tweet retrieving service running within a fixed interval in a separate process.

The service will keep running infinity. I realize to stop the process, going to **Manage App** and stop the service explicitly is the only way.

Note, this is not a very battery friendly way. Even the author claims himself.

> Yes, there is a dark side to Android background services too – too
>   many services doing too much stuff in the background will slow down
>   the phone and suck the battery. However it’s not quite what I wanted
>   to bring up in this post, so maybe we’ll come back to resource
>   management etiquette in yet another post.

However, the author no longer update his blog.

I try to stop the service through `TweetViewActivity`.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();              

    try {
        api.removeListener(collectorListener);
        unbindService(serviceConnection);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // catch any issues, typical for destroy routines
        // even if we failed to destroy something, we need to continue destroying
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to unbind from the service", t);
    }

    // New code added by Cheok. Not working. Not sure why.
    this.stopService(intent);

    Log.i(TAG, "Activity destroyed");
}
```

But that doesn't work. I can see the service still running. May I know, what is the correct way to stop the IPC service, once I quit the `Activity`? What is a good battery saving strategy for the above example?

Comment: Perhaps I should move all code in onDestroy to onStop, as from the article, the service creation code in placed on onCreate.

Comment: Well, there is no guarantee that when your onDestroy/onStop will be called. System decision plays a big part here. I believe you service is still running because system haven't really decided to call your onDestroy/onStop methods yet. You can try onPause() method. It will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason it's still running is because the system never called onDestroy.

if you check this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html you can see from the graph that the onDestroy is only called when the system is about to clear your application from the memory, and depending on the memory constrain it might never be called at all.

The only callback that is guarantee to be called is `onPause()` and that's the one you should rely on to stop your service.